# Challenging LEFT OUTER JOIN query grouping by MAX

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, left-join

I have the following two tables:

```
BillingMatrixDefinition
    - id
    - amount

BillingMatrix
   - definition (FK to table above)
   - service_id (FK)
   - provider_id (FK)
   - amount (Decimal)
```

I need to get all BillingMatrixDefinitions that have the `service_id` and `provider_id` that I specify. Here is the SQL query I currently have:

```
select def.id, service_id, provider_id, 
 (case when matrix.amount is not null then matrix.amount else def.amount end) amount
    from billing_billingdefinition def 
        left outer join billing_billingmatrix matrix
        on matrix.definition_id=def.id 
    where (service_id = 25 or service_id is null)
      and (provider_id = 24 or provider_id is null)
```

This gives me the following results:

```
id      service_id  provider_id   amount
1       25          24            200.00
1       NULL        24            300.00
2       NULL        24            800.00
3       NULL        NULL          750.00
5       NULL        NULL          450.00
6       NULL        NULL          750.00
```

However, I need to get the billing amount per id, so I can only get **ONE** item/amount for each `id`. In which case, I want to get the item where the `service_id=24`, and if that doesn't exist, then get it where `service_id=NULL`.

The correct query should give me the following results:

```
id      service_id  provider_id   amount
1       25          24            200.00
2       NULL        24            800.00
3       NULL        NULL          750.00
5       NULL        NULL          450.00
6       NULL        NULL          750.00
```

Notice how now there is no duplicate entry for 1, and I use the line item where a service_id has been entered (use that one if it exists, else use NULL). What would be the correct query to do this?

Comment: You have "*where `service_id=service_id`*". Is it a typo?

Comment: @PM77-1 Just changed it. It was a variable, but I changed it to 24 which is the number it is in the example.

Comment: @eggyal, it's not necessarily falling back to `NULL`, because I need to get the `amount` of that row, not just an id/NULL in the service_id.

Comment: I see, would you be able to show that in the SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anothr way:

```
SELECT 
    def.id                                              AS id, 
    COALESCE(matrix.service_id, matrix2.service_id)     AS service_id, 
    COALESCE(matrix.provider_id, matrix2.provider_id)   AS provider_id, 
    COALESCE(matrix.amount, matrix2.amount, def.amount) AS amount 
FROM 
        billing_billingdefinition AS def 
    LEFT JOIN 
        billing_billingmatrix AS matrix 
            ON  matrix.definition_id = def.id 
            AND matrix.service_id = 25 
            AND matrix.provider_id = 24 
    LEFT JOIN 
        billing_billingmatrix AS matrix2
            ON  matrix2.definition_id = def.id 
            AND matrix2.service_id IS NULL
            AND matrix2.provider_id = 24  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines (utilizing a temporary table):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Results
select def.id, service_id, provider_id, 
 (case when matrix.amount is not null then matrix.amount else def.amount end) amount
    from billing_billingdefinition def 
        left outer join billing_billingmatrix matrix
        on matrix.definition_id=def.id 
    where (service_id = 25 or service_id is null)
      and (provider_id = 24 or provider_id is null);

SELECT * 
FROM Results r1
WHERE IFNULL(r1.service_id, 0) = 
      ( SELECT MAX(IFNULL(r2.service_id, 0)) 
        FROM Results r2 
        WHERE r2.id = r1.id
      );
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14ed3/4) for the 2nd part only (uses already created `Results` table)

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate the amount using `max()` (and of course add a group-by clause) so you get the non-null value if one exists:

```
select
    def.id, service_id, provider_id, 
    max(case when matrix.amount is not null then matrix.amount else def.amount end) amount
    from billing_billingdefinition def 
    left outer join billing_billingmatrix matrix
        on matrix.definition_id=def.id 
    where (service_id = 25 or service_id is null)
    and (provider_id = 24 or provider_id is null)
   group by def.id, service_id, provider_id
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? Your `GROUP BY` sequence will place `service_id` values of `25` and `NULL` into separate sub-groups and `MAX` will have no practical impact.

Comment: I would agree with that, that it looks off.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work as well.

```
select def.id, service_id, provider_id, IFNULL(matrix.amount,def.amount) amount
    from billing_billingdefinition def 
    left outer join (select definition_id, max(service_id) as maxsid from billing_billingmatrix matrix group by definition_id) as t1
        on def.id = t1.definition_id 
left outer join billing_billingmatrix matrix
    on matrix.definition_id=def.id and maxsid <=> service_id
```

Comment: What *appropriate parameters*?

Comment: You are right, I updated my answer after rereading the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT BMD.id, BM.service_id, BM.provider_id, IFNULL(BM.amount, BMD.amount) AS amount 
FROM BillingMatrixDefinition BMD
LEFT JOIN BillingMatrix BM ON BMD.id = BM.definition_id AND (BM.service_id = 25 OR BM.provider_id = 24)
GROUP BY BMD.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe PM 771's answer works here as well, but I decided to use a subselect in the `OUTER JOIN` table, to pre-filter the results before joining.

Here is the final SQL that worked for this:

```
SELECT *,
       (CASE WHEN matrix.amount IS NOT NULL THEN matrix.amount ELSE def.amount END) calculated_amount,
    FROM billing_billingdefinition def
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT t.* FROM (
        select * from billing_billingmatrix 
        where (provider_id=25 
        or provider_id is null) 
        and (service_id=24 or service_id is null)
        ORDER BY service_id DESC
          ) t GROUP BY t.definition_id) matrix
            ON matrix.definition_id=def.id
```