# GROUP BY characteristic in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following SQL table and query as shown in this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37eda/1/0.

The current result look like this:

```
id  definition_id   service_id  provider_id amount
2       1               25              24  200.00
3       1               NULL            24  300.00
20      3               25              24  700.00
30      4               NULL            24  800.00
```

I need to restrict the query to only show one `definition_id` per entry. If there are two definition_ids, it should use the one with the non-NULL service_id. The correct result should be:

```
id  definition_id   service_id  provider_id amount
2       1               25              24  200.00
20      3               25              24  700.00
30      4               NULL            24  800.00
```

What would be the correct SQL query here?

Comment: It's all shown in the sqlfiddle I posted (create table syntax, the query I'm using, etc.) Please take a look at that.

Comment: i mean what have you tried with coming up with the correct query?

Comment: @DanielA.White various `GROUP BY` statements, but I haven't been able to get the correct one to respect what I need to get.

Comment: what if there are two definition_ids with two associated service_ids?

Comment: `select definition_id, max(service_id), provider_id, amount from billing_billingmatrix where (provider_id=24 or provider_id is null) and (service_id=25 or service_id is null) group by definition_id`, this works in the above case, but doesn't seem to work in all cases.

Comment: @Snowburnt -- there wouldn't be, it would only be `(service_id=25 or service_id is null)` <-- from the SQL fiddle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Challenging LEFT OUTER JOIN query grouping by MAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809664/challenging-left-outer-join-query-grouping-by-max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a subselect first order them then group them,normal group by will use the first occurrence of the record , So make it like first `ORDER BY service_id DESC` then use group by

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
select * from billing_billingmatrix 
where (provider_id=24 
or provider_id is null) 
and (service_id=25 or service_id is null)
ORDER BY service_id DESC
  ) t GROUP BY t.definition_id
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62e0b/4)

Comment: @downvoters show some respect and care to explain